# How to completely hide comments in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, comments, hide, show-hide

I'm not sure if this is a good place for this question, but I did see a similar question posted here on overflow.

I'm just getting started with Eclipse as an IDE and having difficulty finding a comments toggle. I'd like to completely hide them sometimes. I've seen suggestions that would allow me to collapse entire comment blocks to a single line, but I'd want to hide ALL comments (single lines, blocks, etc) like in visual studio as a comparison. The goal is to gain the screen space to see more actual code simultaneously.

Anyone know of a way, plugin or otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: If your goal is just to gain the screen space, I guess collapsing the comment blocks should also help.

Comment: @darthvading The goal is just the screen space, however as I stated above: "I've seen suggestions that would allow me to collapse entire comment blocks to a single line, but I'd want to hide ALL comments (single lines, blocks, etc) like in visual studio as a comparison."  Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bad way of doing it but you could set the syntax highlight for comments to be the same as your background color.